# In C, why does incrementing a pointer adds the size of the type the pointer is referring to instead of 1?

Tags: c, pointers, increment

in C(and possibly C++) if you increment a pointer like this:

```
int a[2];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
int* ptr = (int*) a;
printf("%d\n", *ptr);
ptr++;
printf("%d\n", *ptr);
```

You will see that the pointer was incremented by the size of an int(Indicated by the output:

```
1
2
```

). I would expect it to increase the pointer by one and therefore be in the middle of the two ints printing different values.

My question is: Why does it do this instead of increasing the pointer by 1 as someone would expect?

Comment: Because `*(p + x)` is defined to be the same as `p[x]`. And you have no reason to *expect* what you expect.

Comment: This someone expects it to go to the next int. I guess the people that developed the language thought the same way

Comment: You'd then probably be surprised to learn that `ptr += 1;` *also* makes it point to the next element. It is "add one position", not "add one byte".

Comment: Note that code did not demonstrate "the pointer was incremented by the size of an int" as it shows the result of what the pointer referenced and not the value of the pointer. On novel systems, `int*` lives in a different place that `char *` and truly does increment by 1, yet behaves just like OP's code.  C supports many architectures.

Comment: Because "what you expect" for HLL code is not necessarily what you'd expect if you were programming in assembler.  *If* you were programming in assembler, you wouldn't be thinking of pointers, you'd be thinking of addresses, and you'd expect adding 1 to add 1.  But in a high-level language like C (and even though C is relatively low-level, as HLL's go), if you have a pointer to some ints, and you add 1 to it, you expect the pointer to be incremented to point to the next int.  If you wanted to step through the bytes of the int, you would say `unsigned char *cp = (unsigned char *)a`.